# Problem while implementing the correlation coefficient

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm new to PowerBi/powerquery and I was trying to write a function that calculates the correlation coefficient of 2 given lists.

I used the formula in the following image :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

````
let
Function = (l1 as list , l2 as list) => 
    let
        CorCoefNumerator = List.Sum((l1 - List.Average(l1)) * (l2 - 
                                        List.Average(l2))),
        Denominator1 = List.Sum(Number.Power(l1 - List.Average(l1), 2)),
        Denominator2 = List.Sum(Number.Power(l2 - List.Average(l2), 2)),
        CorCoefDenominator = Number.Sqrt(Denominator1 - Denominator2),
        CorCoef = Value.Divide(CorCoefNumerator, CorCoefDenominator)
    in
        CorCoef
in
        Function(Table.ToList([Sales]), Table.ToList([Profit]))
```

The Error message I'm getting is : 
An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: There is an unknown identifier. Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?

One more question : Is there a way to use DAX function while writing power query queries ? becaus when first I tried to compute this correlation coefficient I needed it to work on columns, but since  I couldn't use the DAX functions I had to use my columns as Lists  !


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z3uJ.png
````